# showModalDialog window vertical scrollbar auto set to top

Tags: javascript

While opening showModalDialog window vertical scroll bar automatically goes to middle. How to set that vertical scroll in top?

Comment: can you give us the code with the parameters which you run on showModalDialog with?

Comment: This got nothing to do with ASP.NET please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

From what parameters i see can be passed to the method it doesn't seem to be any direct way to set the scroll position:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759(v=vs.85).aspx